# Copernic Language Settings

Tags: display, language

I live in the Czech republic and when I search for Czech emails using copernic, Czech characters get displayed incorrectly. Support told me to change the "Language for non-Unicode programs" to Czech, that did not help though. I cant enclose images so for example something that should read "Ještě jedna věc" reads "Je tì jediná vìc". How can I make this right? Any hint is much appreciated.

Daniel